# Select next element carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of DIVs, and I want every X second using `setTimeout` to take the next div and set the display to block, and for the other ones to none, how can I do that? Can someone please give me an example?

How can I make it to be infinite, when reaches the last one to start from the first one again.

I know this is a kind of carousel, but I want too see how it's done.

Comment: You need to stop (pause) on mouseover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but here's one way: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Yr3NV/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item active">1111</div>
    <div class="item">2222</div>
    <div class="item">3333</div>
    <div class="item">4444</div>
    <div class="item">5555</div>
    <div class="item">6666</div>
    <div class="item">7777</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var next = $("#container .active").removeClass("active").next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $("#container .item:first");
    }
    next.addClass("active");
}, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
.item {display: none;}
.item.active {display: block;}
```

Using the method of adding/removing a class gives you a little more style control via CSS rather than coding the style into your javascript and avoids the use of any global or closure variables to keep the state.

Comment: Perfectly functional but no reason to keep reselecting the elements. They're a known quantity. Select once and then do all manipulation with the selected set.

Comment: That depends.  The OP doesn't say whether the data is 100% static or not.  Also, this method has the advantage of no stored state, just uses the class names to manage things.  IMO, a few ms of extra execution on each timer doesn't make any difference if the code is simpler.  So, I'd say this is a personal preference rather than a right or wrong way to do it.

Comment: Agreed that it's mostly a matter of preference for a problem like this, and perhaps good for Uffo and others (and us) to be privy to a discussion like this. My personal preference is almost always to avoid going to the DOM and into jQuery functions unless really necessary. In addition to the performance improvements of my approach (and yours could be improved further still by not requiring jQuery/Sizzle to parse your selectors, using find() instead), mine only has one line to maintain (the first) instead of many lines of css in the dom, 3 lines in the js, and probably some in an external .css.

Comment: IMO, I add complexity and global state to get performance only when there's a point to it.  In this case, there's no impact of the performance difference at all on the real world page so I'd rather use the DOM to keep track of things.  So, when the performance difference isn't needed, I go for the simplest and most flexible approach.  You are free to make a different choice in your code.

Comment: Yes, most certainly we are all free to make different choices! As I said, I think it's just good to hash out these issues to highlight what's behind the choices. And to that end, I think it's less simple to have to maintain code in so many places, especially when it also means performance hits. On the other hand, there's a good chance that a dev will want the added flexibility of a class, so that's a plus.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs = $('#container').find('div'),
    index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if (!divs[index]) index = 0;
    divs.hide();
    divs[index++].style.display = 'block';
}, 1000); // fires every 1 second
```

All the usual disclaimers about global scope being a bad idea, but this should give you what you want.

Comment: `setTimeout` should be `setInterval` if you want it to repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when It changes, it set display none but doesn't do display block for the next div

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit ago. Did you try it with this line? `divs[index++].style.display = 'block'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list div").hide();
var current = $("#list div").first().show();
setInterval(function() {
     current.hide();
    current = current.next().length > 0  ? current.next() : $("#list div").first();
    current.show();

},2000);



<div id="list">
<div>1</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>333</div>
<div>4444</div>
</div>
```

Can be seen working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KenwV/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation with `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/EBpTw/

Given a UL with id of "list" and LIs inside:

```
$(function() {
    $("#list li:gt(0)").hide();

    function showNextBlock() {
        var currentBlock = $("#list li:visible");
        if (currentBlock.index() == $("#list li").length - 1) {
            currentBlock.hide().parent().find("li:first").show()
        }
        else {
            currentBlock.hide().next("li").show();
        }
        setTimeout(showNextBlock,1000);
    }

    setTimeout(showNextBlock,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cycleDivs(base)
{
    var next = ($(base).next('div').css('display') == 'none')? $(base).next('div') : $('div:first');
    $(base).hide();
    $(next).show();
    window.setTimeout(function(){cycleDivs(next);}, 1000)
}
window.setTimeout(function(){cycleDivs($('div:first'));}, 1000);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8hfBd/

Answer (score 0):

**[DIV LOOP DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aboger/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
var i=0, len=$('#parent div').length;
(function loop(){
  $('#parent div').eq(i++%len).fadeTo(700,1).siblings().fadeTo(700,0,loop);
})();
```

**HTML example:**

```
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="children ch1">I'm DIV 1</div>
    <div class="children ch2">I'm DIV 2</div>
    <div class="children ch3">I'm DIV 3</div>
    <div class="children ch4">I'm DIV 4</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS basic setup:**

```
  .children{
    position:absolute;
  }
```

---

And here is one with a mouseover **pause** :

**[DEMO with mouseover pause](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vYNzm/)**